# Dynamic Query in Hibernate. Inputs will change as per User enter

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate with spring frame work. I have a problem that i have a search screen from where user can enter values in five fields, now it is totaly depend on user that user enters one, two or what combination of fields. Now i have problem to creating the dynamic Query according to the User inputs.

Comment: What should be done with the five fields?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for Hibernate Criteria API.